# My div bg-color for button was too wide even tho i use the same attribute like other button before

Tags: android, html, css, web

[The CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQyu3.jpg)

About-text button css:

```html
<div class="about-text">
  <h2>About</h2>
  <h5>Developer & <span>Editor</span></h5>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <button type="button">Let's Talk</button>
</div>
```

And contact-me button-two css:

```html
<div class="contact-me">
  <p>Let Me Create You A Pretty Website</p>
  <a class="button-two" href="#">Hire Me</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the "button" surrounded by a tag with the `class="contact-me"`? Otherwise it will not work according to the CSS on the image. Apart from that, please don't post images of source code, but post it as you posted the HTML code. Of course you can also post the picture to clarify the presentation.